# VMR9 shif bug in MS Windows 10 1703

Tags: windows, directshow

my app uses VMR-9 for video rendering using Directshow. The app has the main window where I attach the first video source and the second window is for the second video source.  I overlap the second window on the main window (Picture in Picture effect).

In MS Windows 10 1703 version I met the strange effect - if I shift the app to the right part of screen, the second window loses video. But Directshow graph shows me that VMR9 receives all video frames on the second window.  See the attached screenshot:

[image]

I don't think this is a bug in the video driver. Because I caught that effect on the other PC with another video card. On other Windows the app works well.

Any ideas?

**Additional info:**

here is a graph for the overlapped window:

[image]

It is not a real PiP. This is only a preparation for it. I call the second window only for the definition of position of the second video source into the main window. After that operation the second window will be closed and the second frames will replaced into the main frame. After it is not any problem. For that preparation I create a graph for each window in the windowless mode

Comment: There is a lack of detail here: graphs, media type, do windows overlap or just VMR inputs etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by replacing VMR9 on the Sample grabber in the second window.  The grabber captured frames and painted them in that window by using the method BitBlt:

[enter link description here](http://kvy.com.ua/transformation-of-opencv-image-to-mfc-image-in-msvc-project/)